# Group files by type and sort them by date in "Visual Studio Code"

Tags: visual-studio-code

I always find it useful when grouping my project's files by their types, then sort them by their modified date, as shown in the snapshot below from MATLAB.

[image: example from MATLAB]

How can I do similar to that in the "Visual Studio Code"? I know that I can do "only sorting" by type in Settings==> Features ==> Explorer ==> Sort order => "type", but this is not enough.

Is there an extension or something that can do the grouping "by type"  and the sorting "by date"?